# How to extract data (folders, content, portfolio, surveys, emails) from ExactTarget 1.0 (MarketingCloud)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, migration

Our team needs to migrate all the contents from Exact Target 1.0 to Exact Target 2.0 (Marketing Cloud). We need to migrate all the images, emails, and contents from the "Content" section.

Is there a way to do this (not manually)?.

If there is a way, how can we implement it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only way I know to migrate without you having to do it, is to hire either a partner or SFMC to do it for you.  This is very expensive though - especially if you have a lot of files/subscribers.  Otherwise you would need to build something through the API/SDK to do it for you - which I can testify sounds much easier than it is.

Comment: @Gortonington do you have a link with examples? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way we find was with the following program in Java:
https://github.com/MichaelAllenClark/exacttarget-soap-java
We change and use this program to extract and upload all the information from Folders, Portfolio, Emails, and Triggered Send from ET1 to MC2. 
However, we had to upload the contents and the templates manually. 
This program helped us a lot solve that problem. I still using it to extract information now from MC2.

Answer (score 0):

Check This page contains information about retrieving and selecting object contained within the Portfolio and associated subfolders of a given Marketing Cloud account. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/selecting_the_contents_of_a_portfolio_folder.htm